# Chrome Device Emulator Issue

Tags: google-chrome, emulation, device

So, my chrome device emulator is doing a very silly thing.

It is only showing a tiny corner of the page in the emulator. When I look on my actual phone at my page, the page loads just fine, but when I look in the emulator I see only a tiny bit of the screen. This is true for every website, including google.

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem? I've searched google and stack for solutions but I haven't seen anything related to this.

I've tried restarting chrome, restarting my computer, and making sure my software is up to date but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, I think it's a problem related to the last update, waiting for a fix. Anyway if you set the emulator to 'responsive' mode and 'desktop' view, it should be fine.